# Trigger the change event of a textbox in jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp:TextBox with asp:RegularExpressionValidator to validate if it's a number. Obviously an onchange event will be attached to this textbox while rendering. Also I add a change event at $(document).ready to make some calculation when the value is changed.

```
<asp:TextBox id="myText" runat="server" />
<asp:regularexpressionvalidator id="myRev" ControlToValidate="myText" runat="server">*</asp:regularexpressionvalidator>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id$=myText]').bind('change',function(){
           //do something
    }).change();      //force the change event at the very beginning
});
```

My function will be executed later than the .net generated js because of the register time. But the asp.net js throws an error. I traced in the js:

```
   function ValidatorOnChange(event) {
       ...
   }
```

and found that all of event.fromElement,event.toElement,event.srcElement are null which causes the exception. Did I do something wrong? Any solutions? Thanks.

**EDIT**

It's proved to be a MS bug, working fine in ASP.NET 4 vs2010.

Comment: Do you need the .net handler to run, or just the jQuery one?

Comment: @Nick Craver:$(XXX).change() will trigger all its change events. But why the generated js gives an error? I think it should be fired correctly.

Comment: Instead of `$('[id$=myText]')` use `$('#myText')`

Comment: The errors are probably happening because jQuery doesn't set up the global `event` object when you simulate an event.  (Guessing.)

Comment: @Pointy - It's asp.net, *#$%ed up IDs when generated, at least until 4.0.  @Danny - I know how `.change()` works, I was asking if you needed/wanted the .Net event handler to run :)

Comment: @Nick Craver I need my change event to be well triggered. Do not care about .net one at the beginning.

Comment: Ah OK.  Still isn't it possible to get at the real ID (the "client ID")? I don't like the idea of burning client CPU for no good reason.

Comment: @Pointy Generate such code in code behind using C#, Control.ClientID,but it's not a good idea to write js in codebehind, because it's hard to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Including Pointy's point (I crack myself up) about ID, you can re-write it like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#<%=myText.ClientID%>').change(function() {
    //stuff
  }).triggerHandler('change');
});
```

Without seeing exactly how your other event is attached, [`.triggerHandler()`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) would be my best suggestion, as the event doesn't bubble up for capture by the .Net handler.

Comment: Not working, i think triggerHandler() is the same as trigger() in this issue. The change event generated by .net will be fired in both of them. triggerHandler() will not trigger browser events, but the .net js is not a browser event.

Comment: @Danny - Since it's bound directly to the element, you'll want to use the approach here for firing the change event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168596/programmatically-triggering-events-in-javascript-for-ie-using-jquery

Comment: @Nick Craver Thank you so much to help me find such useful docs! I'll try their solution!

Comment: @Nick Craver I'm sure now it's a MS bug. I create a web application in both VS2008 and VS2010 with the same code. In 2008 the bug occurs while in 2010 everything is OK.

Comment: @Danny - .Net 4 changed a *lot* of things, this was one of many to cope with situations exactly like this one., if you target .Net 3.5 in Vs 2010 you'll see the same error.

Comment: @Nick Craver Yes I know that, here I say VS2010 means .Net 4 which is integrated. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Pack your calculations in a function and call it on ready event instead of triggering a change:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id$=myText]').bind('change',function(){
           doCalc(); // or doCalc(this) or whatever you need
    });
    doCalc();
});
```

Comment: Without knowing the inside of that method that's a long shot, and it can be done *much* shorter: `$('[id$=myText]').change(doCalc);`

Comment: Yeah, valid point, usually I do it shorter style, focused on the main point now to make it more visible.

Comment: I wonder why the event is fired incorrectly. I'm using the correct grammar.